# How to specify resource provider version in the Terraform using AzureRM provider

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I use Azure ARM templates for deploying Azure resources.
Now I have been asked to convert a few of the ARM templates into Terraform files.

I am new to terraform world. I just went through some online examples of creating Azure resources using Terraform's AzureRM provider. but, nowhere did I find a way to set the API version for the Azure resource provider.

For example, In the ARM template, we can specify "apiVersion" for any resources but in the Terraform there is no option to choose the API version.

Does anyone know how to choose API Version in Terraform for Azure?

Comment: [how to change the API version in Terraform.](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1280#issuecomment-391190233) and [API version used is older one while creating VM in azure via terraform](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/api-version-used-is-older-one-while-creating-vm-in-azure-via-terraform/36565)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terrform we don't speficy the `api version` for each resource likewise we do in ARM template.

In terraform we only use the AzureRM provider version. If you are not mentioning specific version it will take the latest AzureRM provider version

**The Azure Provider can be used to configure infrastructure in Microsoft Azure using the Azure Resource Manager API's.**

Like below

```
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
          version =  "=3.10.0"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }


data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "v-rasXXXXree"
  #location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example-2" {
  name                = "peternetwork2"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}
```

[image]

For more information please refer this official [***terarform document***](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs)

Comment: does that mean if I need to target a specific apiVersion in Terraform then that is not possible?

Comment: Specific API version for resource is not require here but you can specify the Spefic version of AzureRM.